# How to fix "zip: not a valid zip file" error in Go?

Tags: go

I'm newbie in Golang. I use [a link](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx/) to  read xlsx file:

```
    filePath := "controllers\\foo.xlsx"
xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(filePath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

My program run on window os.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Feed a valid `xlsx` file to `xlsx.OpenFile()`. Make sure the file exists, accessible and that it is a valid `xlsx` file.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a valid zip file? You can test by renaming foo.xlsx to foo.zip and using a compression program (unzip, 7zip, etc.) Maybe it got mangled somehow, somewhere?

Comment: excelize does not support old style xls, only works on xlsx (https://github.com/qax-os/excelize/issues/44)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
    file, fileHeader, err := req.FormFile("theAttachmentfile")

    if err != nil {
      do what you wanna do
    }

    xlsx, err := excelize.OpenReader(file)
    if err != nil {
      do what you wanna do
    }
```